# Silverlight 3.0 : How do I get grid children by x:Name?

Tags: silverlight-3.0, grid

Let's assume that I've got XAML representing a Grid with some children in it, each child is a different control, with a x:Name. How do I "get" those controls from code by name ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the code that you are writing is in the code-behind file for the xaml file, then Visual Studio should automatically generate member variables containing references to any named elements in the xaml file. So if you have a Button with x:Name="myButton", you can access this button via this.myButton.

If you want to reference a named element from somewhere other than the code-behind file, you can call FindName on the element to the named element, e.g.:

```
Button myButton = myGrid.FindName("myButton") as Button;
```

where myGrid is a reference to the Grid in question.

Comment: woot! this works. I found an alternative which is a bit more complex but works as well :

private Button myButtnon;
foreach(FrameWorkElement fe in myGrid.Children)
{
    if(fe.GetType() == typeof(Button) myButton = fe as Button;
}

Comment: Note that myButton would be a field with internal accessibility hence even from code outside the code-behind file you can access it without resorting to FindName.

Comment: if you had any idea how long i searched for this simple answer! thanks for the straight question aswell

Answer (score 1):

Each control with an x:Name has a field created for it in the partial class that gets created for the XAML.  This field has an internal accessibility.  Hence from code with in the "code-behind" cs (why do I hate that term?) you can simply use the control name directly in code to access it.

Comment: Would you be so kind and elaborate that?

Comment: I think he means, if you have x:Name="MyNamedControl". Once you compile it, the Reference.g file will automatically have it availble so you can just type this.MyNamedControl

Comment: But if you are doing templating, this won't happen and you should use FindName